# adding html from javascript but not working jQuery toggle function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

here is my js function to load html

```
function getLeftCategories() {

    var id = 3;
    $.getJSON("/api/kategori/getKategoriByTedarikci/" + id, function (data) {

        var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);

        $.each(obj, function () {
            if (this.UstKategoriId == null) {
                var kTop =
                    '<li>' +
                        '<a>' + this.KategoriAdi + '<span>+</span></a>' +
                        '<ul id="ulAltKategori">' +

                        '</ul>' +
                   '</li>'
                $("#ulKategoriler").append(kTop);
            }
        });

        $.each(obj, function () {
            if (this.UstKategoriId != null) {

                var sTop =
                    '<li>' +
                        '<a>- ' + this.KategoriAdi + '</a>' +
                    '</li>'
                $("#ulAltKategori").append(sTop);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

this is my html side

```
<div class="box">
<div class="box-heading">Kategoriler</div>
<div class="box-content">
    <div class="box-category">
        <ul id="ulKategoriler">

        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

here is my script function to toggle

```
$(function () {
    $('.box-category a > span').each(function () {
        if (!$('+ ul', $(this).parent()).length) {
            $(this).hide();
        }
    });
    $('.box-category a > span').click(function (e) {
        debugger;
        e.preventDefault();
        $('+ ul', $(this).parent()).slideToggle();
        $(this).parent().toggleClass('active');
        $(this).html($(this).parent().hasClass('active') ? "-" : "+");
        return false;
    });
    $('.filter-active span').click();
});
```

if i add the html from javascript  toggle function  is not working am i missing something which one is load to page first time  ?

Comment: where is it not working?  Do you get into the debugger?

Answer (score 0):

If this is dynamically loaded html then you will need event delegation to handle this

```
$(document).on('click', ".box-category a > span", function () {
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change your script:

```
$('.box-category a > span').click(function (e) {
  debugger;
  e.preventDefault();
  ...
}
```

to

```
$('.box-category').on('click', 'a > span', function (e) {
  debugger;
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
  ...
}
```